# Why this JavaScript code doesn't work?

Tags: javascript

I have for loop which goes through the array with arguments. When next argument is "?", "&" or "||", it shouldn't add comma, however, it always adds. I couldn't understand why, here is the code:

```js
var args = ["arg1","arg2","?","arg3"];
var query = "";
for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {

  switch (args[i]) {

   case "?":
    query += " where ";
    break;

   case "&":
    query += " and ";
    break;

   case "||":
    query += " or ";
    break;

   default:
    if (args[i+1] != "?"); 
    {
     query += args[i] + ", ";
     break;
    }
    query += args[i] + " ";
    break;

  }

 }
document.write(query);
```

When I type this (this is splitted by " " and sent to array args):

```
arg1 arg2 ? arg3
```

It prints it like this:

```
arg1, arg2, where arg3, // while it should be arg1, arg2 where arg3,
```

Thanks for helping people, problem was caused by an extern script. And yes, **I removed** semicolon ;)

Comment: where is it different `arg1, arg2, where arg3, // while it should be arg1, arg2 where arg3,`?

Comment: @NinaScholz that comma after `arg2` before `where` is not wanted apparently.

Comment: Prints where? You're probably "printing" an array, and its `toString` method adds the comma.

Comment: @Teemu When I print query variable. Query variable is string and is defined before this loop.

Comment: in your default case why  if (args[i+1] != "?");  did you see the last inverted comma at the end? it would be like  if (args[i+1] != "?") { ... ... }

Comment: @SyedEkramUddinEmon Thanks for noticing, I removed it. Still the same.

Comment: `if (args[i+1] != "?"); ` oops!

Comment: @FizzyTea Fixed it. Still the same.

Comment: @Nikola no, it works when you remove the semicolon. I'm running your code in Node and without the semicolon it's fine.

Comment: There is a check mark next to the answers that you can use to select the correct answer. You don't need to edit the title to say "Solved"

Comment: @MattBurland I solved it by myself. I wrote that in title so people wouldn't answer the same thing all the time.

Comment: @Nikola: Then write an answer and mark it. Or, if it's unrelated to what you have in the question, then just close the question.

Answer (score 5):

Your `if` statement is broken:

```
        if (args[i+1] != "?"); // <---- remove that semicolon
        {
            query += args[i] + ", ";
            break;
        }
```

You've got a stray semicolon. It is not a syntax error, but it means the `if` doesn't do anything. The code that adds the comma *always* runs, and exits the `switch` before the code that *doesn't* add the comma.

Comment: @CayceK I have, and I've also run the code. It works without the semicolon.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help out but I solved this. This problem was caused by another array from extern script, now everything works. Thanks for answers anyway.

Comment: @Nikola trust me, you want to get rid of that semicolon.

Comment: @Pointy As I wrote in comments, I already did that. Problem wasn't caused by that.

Comment: @Nikola The problem is ppl vote for the wrong answer without knowing the whole story (for comments here and there). This could misguide other persons to find out the right answer, which is lies in a comment.

Comment: @SyedEkramUddinEmon Except in this case *it's not the wrong answer.* That semicolon dramatically changes the meaning of the code.

Comment: @Pointy that has been figured in comment section of the question and the  questioner replied after that, it wasn't the case for him even before the answer posted.

Comment: @SyedEkramUddinEmon I wrote it at the end of the questioin so people probably wouldn't answer it anymore. Pointy was right , but that haven't solved my problem so I was waiting for another answer and meanwhile I found out what caused the problem.

Comment: @Nikola Then the better approach would be create a update bold section in you questions and mention the answer same way you did it for semicolon or post your own answer and mark that as correct answer.

Comment: @SyedEkramUddinEmon I'll do the second.

Answer (score 1):

You have a semicolon between your if and your block:

```
if (args[i+1] != "?");
```

Should be

```
if (args[i+1] != "?")
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be completely different ways to solve this problem which would make your code easier to extend without deepening trees of `if` or `switch`

A quick example,

```
// define some dictionaries
let logicDict = Object.assign(Object.create(null), {
    '?': 'where',
    '&': 'and',
    '||': 'or'
});

// define some flags
let noComma = false;

// reduce your array
['arg1', 'arg2', '?', 'arg3'].reduceRight((str, e) => {
    if (e in logicDict) {
        noComma = true;
        return logicDict[e] + ' ' + str;
    }
    if (!noComma) e += ',';
    noComma = false;
    return e + ' ' + str;
}, '').slice(0, -1);
// "arg1, arg2 where arg3,"
```

Comment: This is very interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for noticing semicolon guys, problem was caused by an extern script.

Comment: Your script, modified *only* to declare `query` and to hook `args` up to `process.argv` as a Node.js program, did not work with the semicolon but it *did* work correctly once the semicolon was removed.

Comment: Indeed. Leave that semicolon in and it'll still be wrong.

Comment: LOL, I said **thanks for noticing semicolon guys**, and you're still complaining about ..king semicolon?! Yes, that was an error, I know! No matter how it sounds stupid, but it actually worked even with that semicolon (and I'm really not sure how, but I **removed it**). I won't repeat this guys. Please, there's nothing new to say about this. Thanks for noticing, again!